# Vertical output to horizontal output

Tags: regex, perl

For the following piece of code, I'm getting the output one below the other (vertically); however what I want is all in a single line (horizontally).

```
use strict;
use warnings;   
use Getopt::Std;

use vars qw($opt_a $opt_d $opt_m $opt_n $opt_o $opt_s $opt_t $opt_l);
my $drives = `wmic volume get name`; 
$drives =~ s/Name //;
print $drives;
```

It should be:

```
C:\ D:\ F:\ Q:\ X:\
```

However, what I'm getting is:

```
C:\ 
D:\ 
F:\ 
Q:\ 
X:\
```

Comment: 1) You can omit the two lines about option parsing, they are irrelevant; 2) When parsing multiple options, it is more convenient to use a hash, e.g. `my %opt; getopts('a:dm:no:st:l', \%opt);` and now you can use `$opt{a}` for the `a` option, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Replace new line characters with space by using `tr///`:

```
$drives =~ s/Name //;
$drives =~ tr/\r\n/ /;
print $drives;
```

or by using `s///`:

```
$drives =~ s/Name //;
$drives =~ s/[\r\n]/ /g;
print $drives;
```

Note: `\r` and `\n` are new line characters.

Comment: This also removes the final newline marker, which should probably remain, or should be added back on when printing.

Comment: Also, this will replace `\r\n` (the DOS line end sequence) with *two* spaces.

Comment: @reinierpost Thank you for your complement. :)

Comment: I wanted to fix it, but that is not so easy with the `tr` version.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose it's most simple to use the backticks operator in list context; i.e. assign the output to an array. That way you will get one line of output per array element

You also probably want to remove network shares, so a `grep` for lines starting with a letter and a colon will extract those

Finally, if you look at the output of `wmic` using `Data::Dump` or similar, you will see that the lines are padded with spaces so that they are all as long as the longest line. You can use these unwanted spaces using a subtitution, which will also remove the trailing CR and LF

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @drives = grep /^[A-Z]:/, `wmic volume get name`;
s/\s+\z// for @drives;

print "@drives\n";
```

#### output

This is the output of the above code on my own Windows system

```
X:\ E:\ D:\ L:\ R:\ C:\ P:\ H:\ I:\ S:\ T:\ U:\ J:\ M:\ N:\ O:\ F:\ G:\ Q:\
```